# How to set default output when using jQuery .html()?

Tags: jquery, html, default, output

I am working on a simple script and have pretty much figured it out except how to set a default value for the output. How can I get the "Total" to display a default value of 0, like when the page loads? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> demo</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>  
<style type='text/css'>
    #multi
    {
    margin-left:25px;
    }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('input').on('keyup click',function(event){ // run anytime the value changes
        var firstValue = parseInt($('#quantity').val()) || 0; // get value of field    
        var total = firstValue * 5; // multiply them together    
        $('#multi').html(total); // output it
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
<input type="number" id="quantity" min="0" max="250" size="3" value="0"/>
<div>Total<span id="multi"></span><br></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw it in the HTML!

```
<div>Total<span id="multi">0</span><br></div>
```

Comment: Edit: My bad, thanks a lot! So simple I feel foolish now. lol

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but couldn't you just do `$('#multi').html('Total:' + total);`?